# How to get all values from inputs with same name but different index via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, indexing, get

I had a task and now this is kind weird and I don't know, how to do that. So, I have non-specific number of inputs, with same name `car` but different indexes, like `sub`, `master` and `val`.

It looks like this:

```html
<input type='text' name='bike[master]' value='some predefined value 1'>
<input type='text' name='bike[sub]' value='some predefined value 2'>
<input type='text' name='bike[val]' value='some predefined value 2.1'>
<input type='text' name='bike[sub]' value='some predefined value 3'>
<input type='text' name='bike[val]' value='some predefined value 3.1'>
```

I need, that jQuery, after user click on input, take all these values from inputs to one variable, if it will be possible, and send to server, which will put these data together and work with them.

Any idea? It is little bit complicated with indexes for me.

Comment: Didn't understand what actually you want

Comment: If you use `$("form").serialize()` jQuery will do this automatically for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take values of each input which `name` starts with `bike` on click and push it in one array

```js
var result = [];
$('button').click(function() {
  $('input[name^="bike"]').each(function() {
    result.push($(this).val());
  })
  console.log(result)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='bike[master]' value='some predefined value 1'>
<input type='text' name='bike[sub]' value='some predefined value 2'>
<input type='text' name='bike[val]' value='some predefined value 2.1'>
<input type='text' name='bike[sub]' value='some predefined value 3'>
<input type='text' name='bike[val]' value='some predefined value 3.1'>
<button>Send</button>
```

You can also use JQuery `serializeArray()` function and return array, and then use that data

```js
$('form').click(function() {
  var data = $(this).serializeArray();
  data.forEach((e) => {console.log(e.value)});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type='text' name='bike[master]' value='some predefined value 1'>
  <input type='text' name='bike[sub]' value='some predefined value 2'>
  <input type='text' name='bike[val]' value='some predefined value 2.1'>
  <input type='text' name='bike[sub]' value='some predefined value 3'>
  <input type='text' name='bike[val]' value='some predefined value 3.1'>
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**Attribute Starts With Selector**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
 $( "input[name^='bike']" );
```

**[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jenson555/zmsngw6e/)**